# Join integration query involving multiple associations

Tags: mysql, join

I'd like some assistance in fixing this query. Let me explain the background on what it currently does, and then what I need to integrate.

First, here are my current tables.

**users (performers) table**

the users table lists all users. we are going to assume for this query that all users selected are type performers.

```
users
-----------
id
hash
first_name
last_name
```

here is a dump of the users table:

```
id  hash                              first_name  last_name  
 1  092ee63c6698851ba72183388bff1b3b  Jonathan    Kushner    
 2  2d234affe1d08c3394cd499f297d7380  Dustin      Kushner
```

**aliases table**

the aliases table lists all aliases. we connect this table to performers in a further table.

```
aliases
----------
id
hash
title
```

here is a dump of the aliases table:

```
id  hash             title       
 1  436etgfgdggdd    Greatness
 2  54645655gggdgdg  Mr.Darkness
 3  ffsafsdsfdfdssf  Mr.Shadow
```

**performers_aliases table**

the performers_aliases table connects users of type performers to aliases in the aliases table.

```
performers_aliases
----------
id
hash
performer_id (connects to the users.id column)
alias_id
```

here's a dump of the performers_aliases table:

```
id  hash             performer_id  alias_id  
 1  dsaadsasdadsads             1           1
 2  d4544534553                 2           2
 3  adfasdadsadsa               2           3
```

**videos table**

the videos table lists all videos.

```
videos
----------
id
hash
title
```

here's a dump of the videos table:

```
id  hash                             title       
 1  89efaed413163be4557133266ce295b4 crazy sports blooper
```

**videos_performers**

the videos performers table connects videos to a user of type performer.

```
videos_performers
----------
id
hash
video_id
performer_id (connects to the users.id column)
```

heres a dump of the videos performers table:

```
id  hash                              video_id  performer_id  
 1  3a7e0f543af5152c623ad8156079bb73         1               1
 2  c0abf5f50f6382c744a9359d7dbc4c8c         1               2
```

OK. Now let me show you my current query:

```
    SELECT        
      `users`.`first_name`,
      `users`.`last_name`,
      `aliases`.`title` AS `alias`,
      `videos`.`title` AS `video`
    FROM
      `users` 
      LEFT JOIN `performers_aliases` 
        ON `performers_aliases`.`performer_id` = `users`.`id` 
      LEFT JOIN `aliases` 
        ON `aliases`.`id` = `performers_aliases`.`alias_id` 
      LEFT JOIN `videos_performers` 
        ON `videos_performers`.`performer_id` = `users`.`id` 
      LEFT JOIN `videos` 
        ON `videos`.`id` = `videos_performers`.`video_id`  
    WHERE (
        `videos`.`hash` = '89efaed413163be4557133266ce295b4'
      ) 
    ORDER BY `users`.`last_name` ASC
```

This query does the following:

- selects users who are performers for a video. we need to include the aliases tables to grab the performers aliases. (note: performers can have multiple aliases)

Here's a resultset:

```
first_name  last_name  alias        video
Jonathan    Kushner    Greatness    crazy sports blooper
Dustin      Kushner    Mr.Darkness  crazy sports blooper
Dustin      Kushner    Mr.Shadow    crazy sports blooper
```

**As you can see, this video contains 2 performers - Jonathan Kushner and Dustin Kushner. However, Dustin has 2 aliases so it has 2 records for him**

**What I'd like to do is incorporate having video performers connected via aliases to videos, so instead of having 2 records for Dustin since he has 2 aliases, it would only connect to the alias being used for that specific video.**

For example, the output for this video would be:

```
first_name  last_name  alias        video
Jonathan    Kushner    Greatness    crazy sports blooper
Dustin      Kushner    Mr.Darkness  crazy sports blooper
```

This resultset shows only 2 records now, one for Dustin as Mr.Darkness and one for Jonathan as Greatness. You'll note that no longer there exists a record for Dustin as Mr.Shadow since Mr.Shadow was not used as the alias for that video.

Here's my current work as to how to solve this. I've created a `videos_performers_aliases` table that connects videos to performers to aliases.

```
videos_performers_aliases
--------------------
id
hash
video_id
performer_id
alias_id
```

And then I would modify the query from above as follows:

```
    SELECT        
      `users`.`first_name`,
      `users`.`last_name`,
      `aliases`.`title` AS `alias`,
      `videos`.`title` AS `video`
    FROM
      `users` 
      LEFT JOIN `performers_aliases` 
        ON `performers_aliases`.`performer_id` = `users`.`id` 
      LEFT JOIN `aliases` 
        ON `aliases`.`id` = `performers_aliases`.`alias_id` 
      LEFT JOIN `videos_performers` 
        ON `videos_performers`.`performer_id` = `users`.`id` 
      LEFT JOIN `videos` 
        ON `videos`.`id` = `videos_performers`.`video_id`
      LEFT JOIN `videos_performers_aliases`
        ON `videos_performers_aliases`.`video_id` = `videos`.`id`
    WHERE (
        `videos`.`hash` = '89efaed413163be4557133266ce295b4'
      ) 
    ORDER BY `users`.`last_name` ASC
```

As you can see, i added this to the query:

```
LEFT JOIN `videos_performers_aliases`
        ON `videos_performers_aliases`.`video_id` = `videos`.`id`
```

I'd like my output to be the following:

```
first_name  last_name  alias        video
Jonathan    Kushner    Greatness    crazy sports blooper
Dustin      Kushner    Mr.Darkness  crazy sports blooper
```

This insinuates that we have one performer as Mr.Darkness and one performer as Greatness. As you can see, Mr.Shadow is not in the resultset.

Unfortunately, the resultset here is still:

```
first_name  last_name  alias        video
Jonathan    Kushner    Greatness    crazy sports blooper
Dustin      Kushner    Mr.Darkness  crazy sports blooper
Dustin      Kushner    Mr.Shadow    crazy sports blooper
```

This is as far as I've gotten on it.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: First, which one of the aliases do you want to show, lastone? firstone?. Second, this is a really easy query fix, but, you need to clear the *first* step here.

Comment: @oNare I updated my question. Check directly underneath my comment about adding a left join for my new table.